# Migrating MFC app from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I'm trying to migrate a MFC project over from Visual Studio 2012 (where it's compiling fine) to Visual Studio 2013 and I'm getting a heap of undefined errors as per below.

These are all caused when pulling in the precompiled header - and I can only assume I'm including some of the MFC header files in the wrong order - anyone know what order they should be now?
The errors indicate that PGESTURECONFIG is defined in WinUser.h - but it doesn't like me including that anywhere before afxwin.h (it produces different errors if I do indicating "No Target Architecture")

This is what I believe is the relevant section is in the precompiled header currently:

```
#define VC_EXTRALEAN        // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers

#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
#include <afxcmn.h>                 // MFC support for Windows 95 Common Controls
#include <afxcview.h>               // MFC CTreeView, etc...
```

And this is the kind of errors I'm getting:

```
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2092): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_pConfigs'
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2092): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2019): error C2065: 'GID_ZOOM' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2019): error C2065: 'GC_ZOOM' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2025): error C2065: 'GID_ROTATE' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2025): error C2065: 'GC_ROTATE' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2031): error C2065: 'GID_TWOFINGERTAP' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2031): error C2065: 'GC_TWOFINGERTAP' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2045): error C2065: 'GID_PAN' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2045): error C2065: 'GC_PAN' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2051): error C2065: 'GID_PAN' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2051): error C2065: 'GC_PAN_WITH_SINGLE_FINGER_VERTICALLY' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2057): error C2065: 'GID_PAN' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2057): error C2065: 'GC_PAN_WITH_SINGLE_FINGER_HORIZONTALLY' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2063): error C2065: 'GID_PAN' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2063): error C2065: 'GC_PAN_WITH_GUTTER' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2069): error C2065: 'GID_PAN' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2069): error C2065: 'GC_PAN_WITH_INERTIA' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2953): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2953): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetCurrentGestureInfo'
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2954): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2956): warning C4183: 'GetCurrentGestureInfo': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2986): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PTOUCHINPUT'
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2996): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PTOUCHINPUT'
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(3009): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_pCurrentGestureInfo'
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(3009): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(2955): error C2065: 'm_pCurrentGestureInfo' : undeclared identifier
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Your small header sample compiles fine when saved as `stdafx.h` and then compiled with a source that only does `#include "stdafx.h"` with `cl /c /Yc stdafx.h stdafx.cpp` so there must be something else going on. Your error list appears to be related to Win8 features. Make sure you have defined `_WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER` to limit the version of Windows that you want to support. @Bathsheba: unhelpful. In a corporate environment we don't get to just change our tech base on a whim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem today after converting a Visual Studio 2010 project to Visual Studio 2013.
In my case, it turned out to be "hard coded" WINVER define injected via the project's C++ configuration properties (preprocessor definition section), where WINVER=0x500 was defined ages ago.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting `Properties -> C/C++ Preprocessor Definitions` to

```
NTDDI_VERSION= 0x06030000;WINVER=0x0A00;_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have added these settings into stdafx.h file and it worked for me:

```
WINVER=0x601;
_WIN32_WINNT=0x601;
_WIN32_WINDOWS=0x601;
_WIN32_IE=0x601;
```